# How can I programmatically clear the RAM in swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

In an iPhone, you can clear the RAM by holding down the power button, releasing it and then holding down the home button. I want to achieve this programmatically.

Comment: There is no need to do this, development is already with ARC.

Comment: "clear the RAM"? Maybe you should call `abort`. That will certain clear _your_ app's part of the RAM.

Comment: Why do you want to "clear the RAM"? Why would you want to do this from an app?

Comment: If makes no difference even if you do it manually. Craig Federighi, Apple SVP and iOS boss [said so](https://9to5mac.com/2016/03/10/should-you-quit-ios-apps-answer/)

Answer (score 2):

There is no public API to do this, and doing it with the button combination is generally a bad idea anyway.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15681489)

Comment: Sometimes, as is the case here, the answer to "how do I X" is "you can't".